# Easiest way to insert cloud (image) into falling snow with canvas + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I have adopted a Canvas falling snow solution from [webbreakstuff](http://blog.webreakstuff.com/2010/11/building-a-canvas-snowglobe/).

Now, I would like to make it appear as if this snow was falling out of a cloud.

I have a cloud image, `cloud.png`.

I would like to create it via JavaScript like so:

```
var cloud = new Image();
cloud.src = "cloud.png";
```

Now, I want to have it draw in front of one of the two canvas's (either `bgcanvas` or `fgcanvas`) but I cannot figure out how to do that properly in accordance with the `context.drawImage`.

Could someone help me figure out where to put this image, and how to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two canvas elements, fgcanvas and bgcanvas, fgcanvas is in front.

```
var cloud = new Image();
cloud.src = "cloud.png";
//I am assuming that both canvases are in the same position.
var ctx = fgcanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(cloud, sourceOfSnowX, sourceOfSnowY;
```

Should draw cloud.png at the orgin of the snow.